# How to draw over minipage in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, minipage, minted, code

I've got a code snippet, that I'd like to annotate with arrows, boxes, and bubbles pointing to the various parts of the code.

Right now, I've got the code in a `minted` environment, inside a `minipage`, inside a `tikzpicture`.

I'm wondering, is it possible to draw on top of the minipage, so that I can point to various parts of the code inside the minipage with arrows?

What I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=blue, fill=green!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,  baseline=-3.5cm]
\node [mybox] (box) {%
\begin{minipage}[t!]{0.5\linewidth}
Foo
\end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[t!]{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{minted}{haskell}   
let 
  map = \f -> \l -> case l of
    [] -> []
    (a :: b) -> (f a) :: (map f b)
in case map (\x->x) [1,2] of
        (h :: t) -> (h,t)
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}

};
\end{tikzpicture}
%

\end{document}
```

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Maybe use the TikZ library `tikzmark`?

Comment: The contents of the node is much too wide for the width of text. First, the box itself takes up width and then you also have space between the two `minipage`s.

Comment: @cfr So, right now I'm using the left minipage to push the minted environment to the right, but that could easily change. The point is to leave space for the diagrams I'd like to add on top.

Comment: I would suggest using **tcolorbox** for the background box and to align the two parts you want aligned. However, I don't know about marking up the code. It seems that `tikzmark` works with **listings** / **lstlistings** and has specific code to modify the hooks provided, but **minted** isn't mentioned. (For some reason, I thought it was, but I must have been confused.)

Comment: Thanks. I might just forgo the background on the minted, and do each line as its own environment, or use listings. If I lose the highlighting, it's not the end of the world.

Comment: Someone else will probably have a better idea than me. I've never used **minted** but it seems quite popular.

Comment: minted appears to be very fragile.  You can't even put inside \raisebox.

Answer (score 5):

If you can change to `listings`, with `tikzmark`, `tikzmarklistings` library and `tcolorbox's` `comment and listing` option you can do something similar to what you want. This is just a starting example. You will need to customize `tcolorbox` and listing, but also fight with how to define `comment` to fit your needs.

[image]

Following code shows how to do it. `tcolorbox` offers a `listing and comment` option which allows to include any text beside a listing. A `mybox` has been declared with a parameter which can be used to define the comment you want.

Because `\usetikzmarlibrary{listings}` is loaded several `tikzmarks` are defined for every listing line. You need to name every code fragment with `name=...`, then `pic cs:line-name-...` can be used for pointing arrows. While writing this I think that code name should be another parameter but ... I told you, it's just a starting example ;-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcblisting{mybox}[1]{
notitle,
colback=green!30,
colframe=blue,
listing only,
listing options={language=haskell, basicstyle=\ttfamily, name=code},
comment side listing,
lefthand width=.24\linewidth,
#1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mybox}{comment={\begin{tabular}{l}
Explanation\tikzmark{a}\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw (pic cs: a)--(pic cs:line-code-1-start);}\\
\rule{0pt}{1cm}
More Explanation\tikzmark{b}
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw[->,red] (pic cs:b)--(pic cs:line-code-6-first);}
}}
let 
  map = \f -> \l -> case l of
    [] -> []
    (a :: b) -> (f a) :: (map f b)
in case map (\x->x) [1,2] of
        (h :: t) -> (h,t)
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run your code verbatim the arrows don't show up. Perhaps its because cs:line-code-6-first, etc. is never remembered?

Comment: @LeifAndersen I don't understand your comment. I've tested my code again and it works for me. Could you better explain what's wrong for you?

Answer (score 3):

This is as far as I got.  I can only run minted in draft mode and could not get `escapeinside` to work for any characters.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline=(n1.north)]
\node[minimum width=0.5\textwidth,minimum height=3cm] (box) {};
\node[right,green] at (box.west) {Foo:};
\node[draw,ellipse] (n1) at ($(box.south)!.667!(box.north)$) {Explanation};
\node[draw] (n2) at ($(box.south)!.333!(box.north)$) {More explanation};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||] {haskell}
let 
  |\tikzmark{p1}|map = \f -> \l -> case l of
    [] -> []
    (a :: b) -> (f a) :: (map f b)
in case map (\x->x) [1,2] of
        |\tikzmark{p2}|(h :: t) -> (h,t)
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (n1.east) -- (pic cs:p1);
\draw[->] (n2.east) -- (pic cs:p2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```