# Is it possible to use tikzmark inside minted?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minted, code, tikzmark

As I've pointed out in [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287531/how-to-draw-over-minipage-in-tikz?noredirect=1#comment695430_287531), I'd like to have some arrows pointing to parts of a source-code listing.

I know this is possible with the `listings` package, but is it possible with `minted`? That is, is there a way that I can insert a mark at a specific point inside the code minted is displaying?

Comment: I guess you can only try and find out

Comment: @percusse Well, it's more complicated than that, since minted is based on verbatim, you can't just do commands willy nilly, since they will print as text, rather than being interpreted as Latex commands.

Comment: See this one for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60155/minted-doesnt-escape-latex-code-inside-python-docstring TikZ works in every mode

Comment: Doesn't that thread suggest the opposite and that it doesn't work? (Or that nobody there could figure it out, at least.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it appears to work, you just need to specify an escape character (`?` here) to `minted` so you can insert the `\tikzmark`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}


\begin{minted}[escapeinside=??]{py}
def f(x):
    y = x?\tikzmark{here}?2
return y
\end{minted}


See this bit:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\draw[overlay, ->, line width=5pt, red] (0,0) -- (pic cs:here);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @AdamMiller "didn't work" isn't very informative:-) The above code makes the image shown, you need `--shell-escape` (for minted) and to run it twice (for `tikzmark`) If you got an error you could always ask a new question and show the error you got.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "run it twice" was the important bit of information in my case. Now it works for me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Superb suggestion...

Comment: I've been using the above to annotate the source code. One little problem I encountered along the way was if I accidentally have tikzmark with the same name, `tikzmark{a}` in one listing and the same thing in another, the drawings usually get weird. This happens even if the listing are on different pages.

Comment: @PyiSoe yes that's user error, \tikzmark{a} is like \label{a} and writs data to a command with name based on `a` to the aux file, if you do that twice the first one gets over-written you need to ensure the names used are unique

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your clarification. I think I can still manage name clash not to happen by using systematic naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, and in case somebody else stumbles on this: This idea can be combined with the standalone package as well, with a bit of tweaking:

```
\documentclass[multi=apage,varwidth=8cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newenvironment{apage}[0]{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{apage}

  \begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=??]{py}
      def f(x):
        y = x?\tikzmark{here1}?2
      return y
    \end{minted}
    &
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=??]{py}
      def f(x):
        y = x?\tikzmark{here2}?2
      return y
    \end{minted}
  \end{tabular}
  

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \draw[overlay, ->, line width=5pt, red]
    (pic cs:here1) -- (pic cs:here2);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{apage}

\end{document}
```