# tikz with beamer inside minted

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minted

I'm trying to define a `tikz node` inside a `minted frame`. I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, xcolor={svgnames}, aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[
        autogobble,
        escapeinside=||,
        fontsize=\scriptsize,
        breaklines
    ]{php}
        <?php
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'password';
            $dbname = 'STUDENTSREG';
            $conn = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
            if($conn->connect_error ) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            //prepare and bind 
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO STUDENT (SID, SNAME, EMAIL) VLAUES (?, ?, ?) "); 
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$id, $name, $email); |\tikz \node (sink) {dasfkj} ;|
            //set parameters and execute
            $id = 1004; $name = "JKL"; $email="jkl@jkl.com";
            $stmt->execute(); 

            $id = 1005; $name = "MNO"; $email="mno@mno.com";
            $stmt->execute(); 
            echo "Entered records successfully\n";
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        ?>
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

From what I understand this should work but I get the following error:

```
! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 ... }\PYG{esc}{\tikz \node (sink) {dasfkj} ;}
```

I have no idea what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of `|\tikz \node (sink) {dasfkj} ;|`? Removing it solves your problem. There is no node labelled `sink` defined so it causes the error.

Comment: The purpose is to define a node so I can use it in a path later. I know removing it removes the error but that’s not my problem. I need to define a node here.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “there is no node defined.” Doesn’t this statement define a node called ‘sink’ here?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336479/164314).

Comment: Thanks. I’ve seen this answer. That’s what inspired this code. But as you can see it’s not working for me. I’m not doing anything different from the suggested answer that I can identify. Could you point out what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: I’ve made a wrong observation in my first comment. I shall provide you with an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem of how Pygments implements `escapeinside`, see p. 24 of the [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) manual. Apparently the LaTeX control sequence resembles a string or comment for the current `php` lexer.

A workaround is suggested in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/70#issuecomment-111729930). For your particular example, we can use a modified version of the active `!`. **Added**: I also included a `$\bar x\sqrt x$` to illustrate that LaTeX control sequence is broken when doing `escapeinside`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, xcolor={svgnames}, aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\!=\active
    \def!#1#2!{\tikz{\node (#1) {#2};}}
    $\bar x\sqrt x$
    \begin{minted}[
        autogobble,
        escapeinside=||,
        fontsize=\scriptsize,
        breaklines
    ]{php}
        |$\bar x\sqrt x$|<?php
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'password';
            $dbname = 'STUDENTSREG';
            $conn = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
            if($conn->connect_error ) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            //prepare and bind 
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO STUDENT (SID, SNAME, EMAIL) VLAUES (?, ?, ?) "); 
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$id, $name, $email); |!{sink}{dasfkj}!|
            //set parameters and execute
            $id = 1004; $name = "JKL"; $email="jkl@jkl.com";
            $stmt->execute(); 

            $id = 1005; $name = "MNO"; $email="mno@mno.com";
            $stmt->execute(); 
            echo "Entered records successfully\n";
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        ?>
    \end{minted}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: bar vs sqrt]

**Added**: As you can see, `\sqrt x` is fine, but `\bar x` becomes `\bar{␣}x`.

<del>But again, if</del> If you want to simply insert a marker to be used later, then [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336479/164314) by @DavidCarlisle suffices. **Added**: Since no error is generated, I can only assume that `\tikzmark` somehow works as `\sqrt` does.

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn’t inserting the marker run into the same limitations?

Comment: @KG I cannot guarantee. Please check my updated answer.